# Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove every infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

I was wondering if this approach is completely correct for this problem, my approach was to recursively define a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow$ countably infinite subset of an infinite set.

Attempt:
Suppose $A$ is infinite. We will construct a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$, where $B \subset A$, and $B$ is countably infinite. Since $A \neq \emptyset$, we can choose an element $a_{1} \in A$. Set $f(1)=a_1$. Since $A$ is infinite, choose an element $a_2 \in A-\{a_1\}$.Set $f(2)=a_2.$Assume for each $m<n$, $f(m)$ has been chosen. Since $A$ is infinite there exists in element $a_{n} \in A-\{a_1,...a_{n-1}\}$. Set $f(n)=a_n$. Now that $f$ has been defined inductively, $B=\{a_1,a_2,...\} \subset A$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Your set could be any, or is it a numeric set? to me your proof is fine!

Comment: Yeah this is exactly correct

Comment: Assuming [$\mathbf{DC}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) or maybe something a little weaker, this is fine, but some people might bristle at the use of the term "construct" in this context...

Comment: You have the idea. Are you worried about the rigor of your language in the proof?

Comment: I think the 'right' thing to do here is to choose an axiom to construct things and formulate the problem as "such axiom implies that.. ". Indeed, this kind of problems are very often axiom dependent, as @Brian Moehring pointed out. I guess that countable axiom of choice is enough, or equivalently countable Zorn Lemma. The latter is usually very confortable to construct things; check it out if you want to formalize your argument!

Answer (score -1):

Nerding on Wikipedia I discovered the following facts. A set that admits an injective function from natural numbers is called "Dedekind-infinite". An infinite set is one that is not in bijection with a finite set $\{0, \ldots, n\}$.

Suppose we assume the Zermelo-Frankel (ZF) axioms. Then:

1. We always have that a Dedekind infinite set is infinite, because there exist no injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite set.
2. Assume the countable axiom of choice ($AC_{\omega}$). Then your proof can actually be formalized to choose all the values $f(n) $ "together". This is a very subtle point, but you should be aware that generally without the axiom of choice very pathologicsl things can happen, see for example the Banach-Tarski paradox.

Logicians would write this point as $ZF +AC_{\omega} $ proves "infinite $\Rightarrow$ Dedekind-infinite".

3. If we don't assume the countable axion of choice, surprisingly there exist infinite sets which are not Dedekind-infinite! As far as I understood, this proof is not constructive however, so it is kind of a monster.

In this case, logicians would say that the equivalence "Dedekind-infinite $\Leftrightarrow$ Infinite " is strictly weaker than the countable axiom of choice.

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote?